# Either my CSS file is not linking to my HTML properly or Jumbotron won't change text colors

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue setting my text color. I want to set the h1 element to #513271 but it doesn't seem to want to work. Below is my current code and below that are several solutions I've tried that also did not work.

My CSS is saved as stylesheet.css & it is in the same folder as my HTML (which is tributePage.html).

```css
jumbotron h1 {
  color: #513271;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="\stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<html>

<head>
  <title>Lizzy McGuire, an Evolution</title>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <body>
      <h1 style="jumbotron-h1" class="text-center">Hey now, hey now.</h1>
    </body>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

---

I have also tried the following solutions. I have literally tried all of these by themselves, in various combinations, etc.

1. **Change the CSS file path**

   - C:\Users\Ashle\Coding\Assignments\FCC -- Tribute Page\stylesheet.css
   - C:\Users\Ashle\Coding\Assignments\FCC -- Tribute Page\
   - \stylesheet.css (I've used \ through \\\)
   - stylesheet.css\
2. **Change the external CSS link style** (no spaces between side carets, just included them so this would print below)

   - < link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/ >
   - < link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" >
3. **Change the h1 element name in CSS**

   - h1, #h1, .h1
   - jumbotron h1, #jumbotron h1, .jumbotron h1
   - jumbotron-h1, #jumbotron-h1, .jumbotron-h1
   - purple text, #purple text, .purple text
   - purple-text, #purple-text, .purple-text
4. **Change the font color with an inline element**

   - < h1 style="color:purple;" class="text-center" >Hey now, hey now.< /h1 > *Now, oddly enough, THIS will turn the title purple.*

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<body>` cannot be where it is and you have no doctype. Your class name is also not specified correctly in your CSS. Too many problems here. A thorough mess.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for pointing all of that out! Guess I couldn't see the forest for all the trees. It is a thorough mess indeed, but that's the joy of learning. Really appreciate your time & assistance!

Answer (score 0):

For your CSS what you want is

```
.jumbotron h1 {
    color: #513271;
}
```

Note the period before jumbotron to indicate it's a class

Comment: His HTML is thoroughly invalid.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for your help!! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

I hope my answer help you:

This is your original code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lizzy McGuire, an Evolution</title>
  </head>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <body>
        <h1 style="jumbotron-h1" class="text-center">Hey now, hey now.</h1>
      </body>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

You cannot have a div element outside the body tag.

You need to include the link to css file in the head tag. Fix your code like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Lizzy McGuire, an Evolution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Hey now, hey now.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

You can see that in your css file you declare a 'jumbotron h1', but in your HTML code jumbotron appear to be a class, and to style a class in external css file you need to a dot (.) before the class name. Your css need to look like this:

```
.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #513271;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! It's amazing what becomes so blatantly obvious once someone else points it out.

Comment: No problem Ashley :)

Answer (score 0):

Your  tag is not properly placed nor your external css  tag is missing.

and

the class is not used for styling (except if you used bootstrap).

Here is the correct one:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lizzy McGuire, an Evolution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dir/style.css" > <!-- put the external css link here -->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1>Hey now, hey now</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
  jumbotron h1 {
    color: #513271;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I recommend you to practice doing external css files instead of inline/internal.

Comment: Hey Aegir, thank you!! I'm still learning so I greatly appreciate it whenever someone takes the time to stop & help me.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my stylesheet was not being reflected in my HTML doc.  I finally figured out that my .css file was actually a .css.txt file.  "mystyle.css.txt".

In any directory on your computer (I used the one the html/css files were in) click *view* at the top, then *options*.  Select the *view* tab, then uncheck the option "*Hide extensions for known file types*".  When this was unchecked i was able to delete the .txt extension from the .css file and it became a true .css file and reflected in my .html doc perfectly.

Comment: This is not related to the question and does not answer this question. SO is not a platform for general suggestions and this area is for specific answers to the question only. Please delete this.